# Reference Request: counting in a field of $-1$ elements.

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, algebraic-topology

In his lectures on [Matroids](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-XzhVrXIVeSu_b29hbX5xJ0bRThokU8a), Ardila goes through two proofs, points out their similarity to one another, and concludes with this intriguing thought:

> So, are you supposed to think that Euler characteristic is kind of like counting in a field of $-1$ elements? Maybe there's something to this. Actually, there's a paper about this that I'll show you if you're interested.

Unfortunately, this paper doesn't appear anywhere in the website. Does anyone know of a paper that explores this? (Free is best, of course, for future visitors. But I do have a university account so I can probably see it even if it's behind a paywall.)

Comment: Why don't you email Ardila? His email address is in the description for the video series, which is also pretty encouraging in this respect. After all, he did say he would show you if you're interested!

Comment: Also, maybe Baez's [post](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/counting/) and Greg Kuperberg's [answer](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6508/what-is-the-algebraic-closure-of-the-field-with-one-element) are relevant. By the way, will you inform us at what point in the lecture series this is mentioned?

Comment: Hmm, those are in the vein of what I was hoping for! (It's toward the end of Lecture 31.)

Comment: Haha so actually I did email Ardila and he didn't remember what he was referring to XD